# w3 page cache with mobile version

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have w3 total cache installed on my WordPress multisite.
I have a problem when trying to activate the "page cache"

I'm using the same template for both mobile version and desktop version while on functions.php I'm detecting the user agent and then sets a constant that defines the device type (DEVICE_TYPE)

Now if the user agent is mobile im using "template_redirect" hook to serve different file templates for mobile user.

Once the page cache is activated this mechanism stops working .
Is there a way to exclude functions php from being cached ? or any other solution that might be applicable  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most page caches only cache the rendered HTML.  There are ways to make specific pages dynamic (thus not cached)...but I don't think this will work for you....as it sounds like technically EVERY page is dynamic.

I don't think there is a page cache mechanism that will work for you, unless you change your mobile approach (think responsive).  This is a pretty big change though, it might not be something that you can or want to do.